# Вывод данных из sql в список <select>

Tags: java, html

Есть элемент select на странице, сейчас в нем прописаны пользователи.

```
    <select size="10" multiple name="hero[]" multiple, id = "users">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        /////
   <option value="20">20</option>
       </select>
```

Появилась возможность получить список этих пользователей из базы, есть контроллер написанный для этого на java. Он получает список list userlist всех пользователей.

Подскажите пожалуйста как запрограммировать вывод этого списка в select.

Comment: Какой шаблонизатор используется для рендеринга этой страницы?

Comment: шаблонизатор не используется

Comment: Тогда у вас ничего не получится. Переходите с использования статичных html-страниц на JSP, JSF, Thymeleaf и т.п.

Comment: Прошу прощения, только пересел на фронт с бэка, не знал что jsp - это шаблонизатор, я думал это обычный сервлет. Да страница где расположен select это jsp страница как и все у нас в проекте.

Comment: JSTL используете?

Comment: да, используется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select id="users" name="heroes" size="10" multiple="multiple">
  <c:forEach var="user" items="${userlist}">
    <option value="${user.id}">${user.name}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```